# How to convert binary number to fraction?

Tags: math, binary, decimal, fractions

How do I convert a binary to fraction such as for example .10101010001? I am trying to convert a binary fraction to decimal fraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be the same way that you would do it for a decimal number.

0.48 in decimal is the same as:

```
4 * 10^-1 + 8 * 10^-2
```

So for binary, if you had something like 0.101 it would be:

```
1 * 2^-1 + 0 * 2^-2 + 1 * 2^-3
```

and so on...

**EDIT (as per request):**

If you would want to obtain a fraction of the number, you could do the following:

Let *n* be the number of digits (e.g. 0.1011 => n=4)

Convert the number as if it did not have a binary point let this be *m* (0.1011 => m=11).

Your result is

```
m / 2^n
```

Comment: isn't there a fast way our teacher explained it for a smaller number but I have a number that looks like this .0101011110 and trying to convert that to decimal by hand is just a pain I was wondering if i could get a x/y form of it because our teacher will accept that

Comment: Added. This is an easy extension of my first part though, and it would behoove you (for tests) to understand what I'm doing and why it works.